# Accessing second MembershipProvider via ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, membership-provider, objectdatasource

I have a project whereby I need to access a second ASP.NET Membership Database to allow for the user data in this database to be managed.

My approach to this is to add a second connection string to the web.config and a second MembershipProvider:-

```
<connectionStrings>
        ...
        <add name="MembershipWebUsers" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>



<membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
     <providers>
         ...
         <add name="MembershipWebUsers" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipWebUsers" applicationName="WebUsers" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
     </providers>
</membership>
```

I could then access the users in the second Provider like this:-

```
Membership.Providers("WebMembershipProvider").GetAllUsers(0, 50, totalRecords)
```

Instead of `Membership.GetAllUsers()` which would use the default provider.

The previous developer has used an `ObjectDataSource` to handle the binding of users to a `GridView` and `DetailsView`.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MemberData" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="System.Web.Security.MembershipUser"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetUser" TypeName="System.Web.Security.Membership"
        UpdateMethod="UpdateUser">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="username" QueryStringField="username" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

However this uses the `DefaultProvider`. How can I override or create my own `ObjectDataSource` to look at a specific provider that I have configured in my `web.config`, and what methods would I have to implement manually.

I need to be able to CRUD a user in a specific provider via the `ObjectDataSource`.

Comment: ObjectDataSource doesn't know anything specifically about Membership. It just uses the static GetUser method on the Membership class because it's declared as a parameter of ODS. Unfortunately, the GetUser method has no overload which would take a provider name as input. What you can do is implement this on another class you would create and direct ODS on this.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes I worked this out by using DotPeek on the Membership class. I ended up rolling my own targeting a specific provider.